# Visual Studio. Можно ли отследить места в которых изменяется переменная?

Tags: visual-studio

Каким-то образом, переменные внутри классов C++, хотя и инициализированы, имеют в нужном месте совсем не те параметры. Тот факт что они нормально работают если их вынести в глобальное пространство, не изменяя остального кода, говорит о том, что где-то переменная изменяется не в моем коде. Отладка показывает только  значения переменной, но не показывает в каком месте вне-моего кода она изменялась. Есть ли какие то механизмы Visual Studio которые могут сделать список мест которые влияют на переменную, тем самым отследить эти события?

Comment: "Где-то изменяется"? Возможно. Но есть еще вероятность, что ваша переменная не "изменяется" магическим образом, а просто никогда и не получала правильного значения. Или что вы осуществляете доступ совсем не к тем переменным, к которым хотели осуществить доступ. Это - более вероятно, чем "необъяснимое" изменение значения переменной. Лучше покажите код.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224031/how-get-a-breakpoint-on-variable-write-in-visual-studio

Comment: Как вариант. Спрячьте переменную в privat секцию класса. Затем создайте метод set для изменения этой переменной и работайте только через него, даже в других методах этого класса. Затем поставьте точку останова на метод set, и каждый раз, когда переменная будет изменяться, Вы получите останов программы.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 не поможет, если значение меняется в результате порчи/записи участка памяти